# How to pull all vertices from a specific Vertex

Tags: modeling, vertices

I want to create an old tv screen look. The only way I know how to describe it is a very round screen that protrudes outwards. I haven't touched blender in awhile and I know you can have one vertex apply to all when pulling outwards. Otherwise it only affects a couple faces around it. (Sorry for the bad explanation)

[image]

Instead of this on the picture I want to pull the vertex and have it apply to the rest of the plane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit Mode Proportional Editing (keyboard shortcut <kbd>O</kbd>). works well.

[image]

Comment: @LordOfPancakes you can mark this as accepted...